# Streching fonts in yAxis to render on PrawnPDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I use **PrawnPDF** to render Poster's PDF. These posters are used to show product prices, so they big size is really important to us.

So I need to strech the **yAxis** of the price's **font** as we do in *CSS3* by using:

```
transform: scale(1,1.25);
```

Has anyone faced this problem before? Many Thanks.

Comment: Don't think PrawnPDF can do css. You might want to explore an alternative to generate PDF from HTML file.

Comment: I do not want to put css into PrawnPDF. I'm just wondering if it has some feature like that. I did not find anything about that at the manual/docs.